# How to use the $ alias for jQuery with seveal source files

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am using jQuery in some custom files added to a Wordpress site, and am using this to allow me to use the "$" shortcut:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(selector).bla();
  // etc
}
```

However, if I want to split my code into several files, this construct needs to exist in each file, and then functions from one cannot be called from the other. How to do this? Can I somehow declare certain functions as global?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) to define modules, then pass the modules in as dependencies.  You can also use it to define jQuery as as dependency so that it can be scoped locally with whatever variable name you want.

```
require(['jquery','somemodule','someothermodule'], function($,module1,module2) {
    $(function() {
        var mod1 = new module1();
        var mod2 = new module2();
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
var myFunc = function($) {
    function toExport() {
            alert($);
    }

    return toExport;
}(jQuery);​
```

Just return resources you need (it can be single function, or object, or anything you want actually.)

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI is actually written a similar way:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {
    ...
}( jQuery ) );
```

This way the `$` is guaranteed to be a synonym for the `jQuery` function and the keyword `undefined` will be defined as parameter with an undefined value.  The `undefined` portion actually fixes some nit picky issues with a few browsers since they don't all handle undefined the same way.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can always **declare** functions *outside* the `jQuery(function() {...});` construct, in global scope.

You just cannot access the DOM before it is ready, which means you **cannot execute** those functions outside `jQuery(function() {...});` if they access the DOM.

---

You can also always create a global variable by assigning a value to `window` property:

```
window.theanswer = 42;
```

Adding many values to the global namespace is not a good practice, and other techniques exist to create modular JavaScript to solve this problem. [See tvanfosson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14000774/218196).